# Rubyで配列の要素すべてを整数に変換したい

Tags: ruby, array

環境：Ruby2.0.0
     Windows8.1 home 32bit

Rubyで配列の要素すべてを整数に変換したいのですが、

```
foo = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

これをなるべく簡単に

```
foo = [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]
```

に置き換えるにはどのようにすればいいでしょうか？

```
foo = ["1","2","3","4"]
i = 0
while i <= 3
    foo[i] = foo[i].to_i
　  i += 1
end
```

個人的こう書いてますが、もっといい書き方があれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

好き好きありますが、こういうのもあります。

```
foo.map!(&:to_i)
```

こうすると `{|hoge| hoge.to_i}` みたいにhogeを二回入力するのを省略できてよいです。

詳しくはここを参考にして下さい。
http://www.xmisao.com/2014/02/09/ruby-array-map-idiom-symbol-to-proc.html

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！さらに短くなって見やすいです。ご提案いただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

速さまでは確認していませんが、こんな書き方ができます。

```
foo.map!{|x| x.to_i}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確かに、一行で簡潔に書けて楽ですね。参考にさせていただきます！

Comment: @TaikiMatsumura さん、元の配列を保存して別の配列を作りたいなら`bar = foo.map{|x| x.to_i}`という書き方もできます。配列の全ての要素に同じ変換をしたいということは結構多いので、`map!`, `map`は覚えておくと便利ですよ。

Comment: `&`(unary ampersand operator)を使って `foo.map!(&:to_i)` と書くこともできます。